# Can't remove software - Installed in NULL

Tags: software-installation, uninstall

I've installed software on our administration machine. The problem is that I cannot start or uninstall the software because it is not in any directory on the machine.

I tried to install it at /pack/CST/... but it is not there and a locate on "CST" or "cst" returns nothing. The software is installed from a DVD and not a repository.

I've tried to reboot the machine, as I thought it might have had something to do with the software being loaded in some kind of tmpfs, but that didn't help.

I've looked through the entire /etc directory to check for any relations to the software, but didn't find anything.

I'm out of ideas. What can cause this problem?

EDIT: I downloaded the iso which I mounted with:

```
sudo mount -o loop /path/to/iso.iso /path/to/mountpoint
sudo /path/to/mountpoint/install.sh
```

Ran the install GUI via an X-session. I chose to install the software in /pack/CST/..., but when it exited it said that the software had been installed to /tmp/... However, there was nothing in tmp, so I decided to reboot the machine and did a full find to see if there was anything left of the software, and removed what looked like it could be related.

It had placed a script in all of the /etc/rs* folders which I removed with:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f scriptname -r
```

I rebooted the machine again, just to be sure. When I ran the installer again, it told me that the software was installed in NULL and I have to remove it before installing it.

/pack/ is a mountpoint for /q/system/pack

I expected the software to be installed in /pack/CST, but it seems to be locked in the system and I am unable to locate where.

Comment: how did you install it? please describe the exact steps. (I doubt you installed it to _my_ administration machine ;) ). How did you try to install it to "/q/CST"? What is "/q/CST" (is it mounted, is it a special volume, what is there now). AKA: please provide more information, especially the actual steps you took, what you expected, why you expect that, what is now different from what you expected, etc.

Comment: There you go. I've edited the OP. Ohh, it is on your machine, I'm that good :-P Hope this is enough information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appeared to be known by the software developer. After gaining access to their support forum, i found this thread. https://www.cst.com/Content/Support/Forums/ShowThread.aspx?threadId=285

The problem is that the installer stores a hidden file ".com.zerog.registry.xml" in /var/.